# Is there an easier way to repeatedly insert lines to the bottom of the list?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, insert

I am trying to add a line to the bottom of a list by clicking a button (Excel VBA). Is this the easiest way to do it? If it is, this code is not working, it stops after selecting "B37". Any advice will be helpful. Thanks!!

Subject 1: xxxxx   --   Subject 1: xxxxx   --   Subject 1: xxxxx
Subject 2: xxxxx   --   Subject 2: xxxxx  --    Subject 2: xxxxx
Subject 3: xxxxx  to  Subject 3: xxxxx to Subject 3: xxxxx
Subject 4: xxxxx -- .................xxxxx -- .................xxxxx
Subject 5: xxxxx -- Subject 4: xxxxx -- .................xxxxx
..............................Subject 5: xxxxx -- Subject 4: xxxxx
............................................................Subject 5: xxxxx

```html
Sub ReferenceDocAddiditon()
'
' ReferenceDocAddiditon Macro
'
'
'
    Range("B37").Select
    If ActiveCell = "" Then
    
        Range("B38").Select
        If ActiveCell = "" Then
   
            Range("B39").Select
            If ActiveCell = "" Then
    
                Range("B40").Select
                If ActiveCell = "" Then
    
                    Range("B41").Select
                    If ActiveCell = "" Then
    
                        Range("B42").Select
                        If ActiveCell = "" Then
    
                            Range("B43").Select
                            If ActiveCell = "" Then
       
                                Range("B44").Select
                                 If ActiveCell = "" Then
    
                                    Range("B45").Select
                                    If ActiveCell = "" Then
    
                                        Range("B46").Select
                                        If ActiveCell = "" Then
    
    
                                        ElseIf ActiveCell <> "" Then
                                        Rows("45:45").Select
                                        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                                    
                                    Range("B44").Select
                                    ElseIf ActiveCell <> "" Then
                                    Rows("44:44").Select
                                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                                
                                Range("B43").Select
                                ElseIf ActiveCell <> "" Then
                                Rows("43:43").Select
                                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                            
                            Range("B42").Select
                            ElseIf ActiveCell <> "" Then
                            Rows("42:42").Select
                            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                        
                        Range("B41").Select
                        ElseIf ActiveCell <> "" Then
                        Rows("41:41").Select
                        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                    
                    Range("B40").Select
                    ElseIf ActiveCell <> "" Then
                    Rows("40:40").Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                
                Range("B39").Select
                ElseIf ActiveCell <> "" Then
                Rows("39:39").Select
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            
            Range("B38").Select
            ElseIf ActiveCell <> "" Then
            Rows("38:38").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        
        Range("B37").Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell <> "1" Then
        Rows("37:37").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        
    Range("B36").Select
    ElseIf ActiveCell <> "" Then
    Rows("35:37").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
```

Comment: Please specify the Programming Language you are using and some examples on what you expect the code to produce.

Comment: I am so sorry I meant to put this, but it is in Excel using VBA. I have chart and a section in this chart may need to be expanded to more than one line. And I may be WAY off here, but I left and hid a line to prepare for adding a line without messing with the section below it or messing up borders. That was my way of thinking, but the main goal is:

Comment: to use a button with a macro assigned that will add line over and over again without messing up the border or the line below .

Comment: Is that more understandable?

Comment: What you've got going on here is just not what you want.  Are you saying you have a border with LINES and you want to INSERT a row between the last row and the BORDER?  And to do that when something happens like a button click event?  The IF statements are checking to see if you already have data in the row?  I'm just not sure I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for everything you are trying to do, but I can tell you what this will do.

Without having to select any cells, except at the end of the macro to return control to Column A of the new row, just inserted, leaving any formatting.

There's probably an easier way to do this, but my brain works like this. Feel free to look for other solutions or adapt this to suit your needs if it's not just right.  Comments in the code should provide insight as to what's going on.

**TESTED:**  see pics

```
Sub InsertRowAtEnd()

Dim lastRow As Long   
Dim lastCol As Long   
Dim sheet As String

    sheet = "Sheet1"    'Name your sheet here.
    lastRow = Sheets(sheet).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row          'Get last Row & col
    lastCol = Sheets(sheet).Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Sheets(sheet).Cells(lastRow, 1).EntireRow.Insert    'Insert a new row before the last row

    For lCol = 1 To lastCol                             'Copy the last row to the inserted row
        Sheets(sheet).Cells(lastRow, lCol) = Sheets(sheet).Cells(lastRow + 1, lCol)
        Sheets(sheet).Cells(lastRow + 1, lCol).ClearContents    'erase the old last row
    Next lCol

    Sheets(sheet).Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Select           'Return focus to the new cell A(row)

End Sub
```

[image: BEFORE]
[image: AFTER]